# How to solve Socialauth-Android for twitter?

Tags: android, socialauth

I am working on Android and I have used Socialauth library into my application to provide facebook and twitter .
It was worked fine some days.
Now facebook is working fine but twitter is not working.

when I am using twitter it is showing following message in log cat

this is not working with Twitter this. It was worked fine before . Now I am getting a twitter Authentication Error. I have added the correct consumer_key, and secret but I am getting like..

**org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthConfigurationException?: Application keys are not correct. The server running the application should be same that was registered to get the keys.**

```
Authentication Error
```

But I have added the correct consumer_key and secret .

Can any one provide the solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Ganesh , Have you used the testing jar socialauth 2.1 . Also I would recommend that you u provide ur own callback url using addcallback method.

Comment: Hi Ganesh , the latest sdk is released. You can now use it.check examples for use.

Comment: Hey Ganesh, was you able to solve the issue? I am also facing the same, can you help me out.

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same problem even with new SDK

Comment: No, not yet got the solution to this issue. If you got solution, please share with me.

Comment: Getting similar issue for linkedin. Is it resolved for you? how you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the device's time and date. The error might occur if future time is selected in settings.

Comment: Thanks Max. I have the same problem and it solved when I set correct the time in setting.

Answer (score 0):

Chechk Callback URL to your Twitter application settings